# Google Map Android: How to disable infinite side-scrolling?

Tags: android, google-maps, scroll

I'm developing Android App, and I want to prevent Google Map from scrolling infinitely to roll around earth.

For up-down scrolling it acts as what I want.
When North Pole(+90 Latitude) appears on top of the Map I cannot scroll up any more.
But when the point(Longitude +180) appears on the right of the map, I can scroll right more and the map shows the leftmost(Longitude -180) part of the world.

I want to disable infinite side-scrolling and make it act like up-down scrolling behavior.
How can I do that?

Comment: What you want is to scroll Map from Up to Down or Vice-Versa.... And what you don't want is to stop scroll form Left to Right and Vice-Versa. Am I right?

Comment: No, I want to disable left scroll when the left boundary of map is -180 longitude, and vice versa.

Comment: Try using `UiSettings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(boolean)`. [Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#map_gestures).